# Classic ASP test if Server can create object

Tags: asp-classic

With this code:

```
Dim xmlDOM
Set xmlDOM = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")
```

How can I test that the CreateObject function has been successful?

Comment: See this link - http://www.chestysoft.com/asp-error-messages.asp . If you have debug messages enabled then you'll get an error message saying "server.createobject failed" and a line reference.  For the record, if you're on IIS7 or later you're better off using MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0

Comment: Thanks, I'll update to 6.0 and enable error messages when back at work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it didn't work you might get an error.  Otherwise, you could use the following code:

```vbs
Dim xmlDOM
'dont fail on error'
On Error Resume Next
Set xmlDOM = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")
On Error GoTo 0 'turn error handling off again'

If Not xmlDOM Is Nothing Then
   'not null: it worked'
Else
   'xmlDOM is nothing.  It was not able to create the object. ' 
   'Check create permissions in COM+'
End If
```